# Prove $[f'(x)]^2<2f(x)$ for any $x$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Let $f: \mathbb{R} \mapsto (0,+\infty)$ be differentiable and satisfy
>   $|f'(x)-f'(y)|\leq |x-y|$ for any $x,y$. Prove $[f'(x)]^2<2f(x)$ for
>   any $x$.

Notice that the assumption conditon gives that $f'(x)$ is of **Lipschitz continuity**, but this seems to be not so easy to use. I guess this maybe need to prove by contradiction.

Comment: Consider in following cases, 1) $f$ is montone. 2) $f$ not simply montone, then let $x \in \mathbb{R}$, let $a$ be the closet point near $x$ where local extremum occurs. then the inequaity gives the result easily.  Then resulting that $|f'(x)|\le |x-a|$ and $f(x) \ge (x-a)^2/2 +f(a) \gt (x-a)^2/2$.
I divide it into cases so as to make computation easier.

Comment: This question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2487452/42969 contains a proof.

Comment: See also: [Proving that, $|f'(x)-f'(y)|\le k|x-y| \implies (f'(x))^2< 2 kf(x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2518388).